# Proof of principle of transmissibility of force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

The principle of transmissibility states

> The point of application of a force to a rigid body can be moved anywhere along its line of action without changing the external reaction forces.

My question is how to justify this statement? Or prove this statement?

It seems really counter-intuitive to me that changing the point of action (within the same line) does **NOT** change what effects it has on the object/body.

Specifically, my gut feelings tell me that two different points of action of force will result in different torques.

Comment: great question.